# AngularJS--Cannot get timer to count down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, factory

I am working on a time management app, and am having trouble getting my timer to work. The primary issue I am having is passing the **timerDuration** value through each function so that **timerDisplay** is automatically updated as the timer counts down.

After several days researching this, I am even more confused. I have read the Javascript docs, AngularJS docs, Mozilla's AngularJS docs, as well as numerous related StackOverflow questions and Angular/Javascript blogs.

There are a number of approaches I have tried: using $scope in the factory, which doesn't work (Angular has docs on this), putting all the timer logic in the controller (not very Angular), and I even tried building a custom directive, which did not work. Methinks I am misunderstanding something, but cannot seem to figure out what it is. By putting the timer logic in a factory service, I hope to gain a practical understanding of how to build services that actually work.

Here's my code:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('TimerCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 'CountdownClock',  function($scope, $interval, CountdownClock){

    $scope.taskTimer = function() {
        CountdownClock.timerDisplay($scope, 1500);
        $scope.start = function(){
            CountdownClock.start($scope);
        };
        $scope.stop = function(){
            CountdownClock.stop($scope);
        };
        $scope.reset = function(){
            CountdownClock.reset($scope, 1500);
        };
    };
    $scope.shortBreakTimer = function(){
        $scope.timer(300);
    };
    $scope.longBreakTimer = function(){
        $scope.timer(1800);
    };
}]);
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('CountdownClock', ['$interval', function($interval){

    return {

        timerDisplay: function($scope, timerDuration){
            var scope = $scope;
            var self = this;
            scope.timerDuration = timerDuration;
            scope.seconds = '0' + parseInt(scope.timerDuration%60);
            scope.minutes = parseInt(scope.timerDuration/60);
            if(scope.seconds > 0 && scope.seconds !== 0){
                scope.seconds = '0' + scope.seconds;
            }
            if(scope.minutes == 0){
                scope.minutes = '0' + scope.minutes;
            }
        },
        start: function($scope){
            var scope = $scope;
            var self = this;
            isStopped = false;
            self.runTimer();
            console.log('start  ' + scope.timerDuration);
        },
        stop: function($scope){
            var scope = $scope;
            scope.isStopped = true;
        },
        reset: function($scope){
            var scope = $scope;
            scope.timer = new timer($scope, timerDuration);
        }, 
        runTimer: function($scope){
            var scope = $scope;
            if(self.isStopped){
                self.isStopped = false;
            }
            if(scope.timerDuration > 0){
                var interval = $interval(scope.timerDuration, 1000);
            }
            console.log('runTimer  ' + scope.timerDuration);
            if (timerDuration === 0 || self.isStopped){
                self.isStopped = true;
                $interval.cancel(interval);
            }
            scope.timerDuration--;           
        },        
        isStopped: function(){
            isStopped = true;
        }
    };
}]);
```

**UPDATE**

I am now able to get **CountdownClock** to work. However, it isn't working correctly. After more research and troubleshooting, I think I have it nailed down to the **timer** function in the **CountdownClock** factory. Even though the initial value of **timerDuration** is passed in as a parameter, and **scope** is set, I get **scope.timerDuration = undefined.**

What is happening to **scope.timerDuration?** I can't seem to figure this out.

**Updated Controller**

```
app.controller('TimerCtrl', ['$scope', 'CountdownClock',  function($scope, CountdownClock){

    $scope.taskTimer = function() {
        CountdownClock.timer($scope, 1500);
        $scope.start = function(){
            CountdownClock.start($scope);
        };
        $scope.stop = function(){
            CountdownClock.stop($scope);
        };
        $scope.reset = function(){
            CountdownClock.reset($scope, 1500);
        };
    };
    $scope.shortBreakTimer = function(){
        $scope.timer(300);
    };
    $scope.longBreakTimer = function(){
        $scope.timer(1800);
    };
}]);
```

**Updated Factory**

```
app.factory('CountdownClock', ['$interval', function($interval){

    return {
        timer: function($scope, timerDuration){
            var scope = $scope;
            scope.timerDuration = timerDuration;
            scope.seconds = '0' + parseInt(scope.timerDuration%60);
            scope.minutes = parseInt(scope.timerDuration/60);
            if(scope.seconds > 0 && scope.seconds !== 0){
                scope.seconds = '0' + scope.seconds;
            }
            if(scope.minutes == 0){
                scope.minutes = '0' + scope.minutes;
            }
            console.log('timer ' + 'scope.timerDuration = ' + scope.timerDuration);
        },
        runTimer: function($scope, timerDuration){
            var scope = $scope;
            var self = this;
            if(self.isStopped){
                self.isStopped = false;
            }
            if(scope.timerDuration > 0){
                var interval = $interval(self.timer, 1000);
            }
            if (scope.timerDuration === 0 || self.isStopped){
                self.isStopped = true;
                $interval.cancel(interval);
            }
            scope.timerDuration--;           
        },
        start: function($scope, timerDuration){
            var scope = $scope;
            var self = this;
            self.isStopped = false;
            self.runTimer($scope, timerDuration);
        },
        stop: function($scope){
            isStopped = true;
        },
        reset: function($scope){
            var scope = $scope;
            scope.timer = new timer($scope, timerDuration);
        },         
        isStopped: function(){
            isStopped = true;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You want to update your DOM each second to show the new time. That is a directive. Learn about directives too while you are at it. [Also check this out](http://momentjs.com/docs/) it may help you without trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, ODelibalta. I will try using moment.js and see if that helps. You're right about the DOM--that is precisely what I am trying to do:)

Comment: I tried moment.js, but decided to return to trying to solve this problem the way I originally intended. I am certain I am missing something that has to do with accessing variables that are inside other functions, or declaring a variable in such a way that it becomes global in the factory scope.